# Exposing an APEX REST endpoint to be called by Jira

Tags: force.com-sites, apexrest, connected-apps

Built an [APEX REST endpoint](https://github.com/nstuyvesant/time-and-billing/blob/master/time-and-billing-service.apex) that handles an inbound PUT operation to update records in an SObject (Time_Entry__c). I want to trigger the PUT from a Jira Automation with a web request whenever a particular Jira Issue field is changed. To the Jira user, the Jira to Salesforce interaction should be completely invisible.

The part I'm wrestling with is how to configure the authentication on the Salesforce side.
One of the use cases for a **Connected App** is, "You can use a connected app to integrate external applications with the Salesforce API, such as a web-based app that pulls in order status data from your Salesforce org."

I've also seen advice in posts saying I should setup a **Site** but the example allowed anonymous access to the endpoint which is not what I want.

There are lots of integrations for Jira to Salesforce but none address my very narrow use-case.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you do not want anonymous integration (you don't! It's rarely the right choice), you'll create a [Connected App](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/connected-app-basics) to define the rubric under which your Jira server will execute an OAuth authorization flow into Salesforce.

Specifically, the Connected App provides a Client Id and Secret that your Jira server will use in executing either the [Web Server](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_web_server_flow.htm&type=5) or [JWT](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_jwt_flow.htm&type=5) OAuth flows to get a Salesforce access token it can use to make REST API calls. [This Trailhead module](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/projects/build-a-connected-app-for-api-integration/implement-the-oauth-20-web-server-authentication-flow) walks through the basic layout using the Web Server flow.

Bear in mind that you'll need a user under which to authenticate - Connected Apps are *not* credentials. That user might be an existing user to which you want Jira's activity associated, a shared Integration User you use across integrations, or an Integration User specific for Jira, depending on your available user count and integration architecture.

Comment: Thanks @David Reed. This helps. One challenge I face is Jira Automation's Send Web Request allows for customized headers but not a flow that would generate a Salesforce Token (https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-articles/Automation-for-Jira-Send-web-request-using-Jira-REST-API/ba-p/1443828) - no callback URL or anything like Named Credentials in Salesforce. Would this eliminate the possibility of using Connected App or is there a configuration that would still work?

Comment: I shouldn't recklessly opine since I know nothing at all about Jira's integration mechanics. Best if it's possible to find a way to do OAuth.

Comment: Jira Automation allows for several steps. Additionally, its "Send web request" appears to support return values. Perhaps I can use the "OAuth 2.0 Username-Password Flow for Special Scenarios", grab the access_token from the response and pass it to my call?

Comment: That flow is definitely less desirable because it involves storing raw credentials, but it sounds like it could be workable if you aren't able to get Jira to cooperate.